# How to write class within class in css

Tags: html, css

This is my `CSS` code:

```
  nav ul li ul li .toggle {
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px; 
  }
```

Now I want to change `nav` into some `class` like `.multilevel`. How can I write `CSS` `class` along with another `class`?

Shall I write like below:

```
.multilevel ul li ul li.toggle {
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px; 
}
```

I think it is wrong. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your HTML, we require a reproducible example to understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result/problem?

Comment: ya i tried but not working, i think that is not correct format

Comment: yes, it is correct to replace `nav` with `.multilevel` it just you've used `nav ul li ul li .toggle` in your first step and `.multilevel ul li ul li.toggle` in second.  Its an typo error of *spacing* between `li` and `.toggle`.

Comment: Here is one difference between these chunks: `li.toggle` is `<li class="toggle">`, and `li .toggle` is smth like `<li><a class="toggle">...`

Comment: Finally i found the alternate way to achieve this, I just used menu tag instead of nav tag. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can use comma separator CSS selectors as below

```
.multilevel ul li ul li.toggle,
nav ul li ul li .toggle {
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px; 
}
```

Comment: if you want to add `multilevel` in `nav` then yes its correct or you can also use `nav.multilevel ul li ul li.toggle`

Comment: @user7357089 syntax is correct, but what exactly you expect to see - we don't know